# How do I prevent Excel from attempting to connect to its links when opening a file with links in Powershell?

Tags: excel, powershell, com

I have a PS script that runs from the Task Scheduler. When a .xlsm file is added to a watched folder it opens this file and gathers specific data from it, then outputs it to a CSV. The problem I've been having recently is with XLSM files that have links to an external SharePoint site. Any time these files are opened with the script it just hangs. If I try to open the file manually Excel first asks me to "Enable Content", then once I click to enable a prompt to input my credentials to connect to the SharePoint site associated with the link.

I can confirm after breaking the link and then running the script that the problem is resolved, so it is definitely this link that is hanging the script up. I've tried looking into methods to break the link before opening the file, but I was not able to gather much. All the resources I could find were in references to updating links via Powershell, not breaking them.

Here are the pieces of my code related to opening the file:

```
$watchedfolder = "C:\Watched"
$filedirectory = Get-ChildItem $watchedfolder | Where-Object {($_.Extension -eq ".xlsm")} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name 

foreach ($file in $filedirectory){
    $sheetName = "Daily Dash"

    #OPEN EXCEL WORKBOOK
    $objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
    $workbook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Watched\$file")
    $sheet = $workbook.Worksheets.Item($sheetName)
    $objExcel.Visible = $false
    $objExcel.DisplayAlerts = $false
    $rowMax = ($sheet.UsedRange.Rows).count
```

I am unsure of what I can add to this opening portion of my script that will prevent the attempt to connect to the SharePoint site. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot test this at the moment, but you need to do the settings for the Excel object **before** opening the file.

Setting the `AskToUpdateLinks` property to $false should do what you ask for.

```
#OPEN EXCEL WORKBOOK
$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$objExcel.Visible = $false
$objExcel.DisplayAlerts = $false
$objExcel.AskToUpdateLinks = $false
$workbook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Watched\$file")
$sheet = $workbook.Worksheets.Item($sheetName)
$rowMax = ($sheet.UsedRange.Rows).count
```

Comment: That worked. On top of this I added values for the parameters UpdateLinks and ReadOnly to Open(), left your suggestion in as well as this edit because why not.  
  
`$workbook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Watched\$file",0,$true)`